# Which CSS3 rule would be a better choice for the same effect?

Tags: css

I have a CSS3 rule that I want to make hide everything inside a given element **except** for any headers, until the user hovers over it. **Which way would be a better choice?** Keep in mind that, in this case, I'm not worried about backwards-compatibility with CSS2.1

### Idea 1

---

```
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) *:not(H1):not(H2):not(H3):not(H4):not(H5):not(H6){
    display:none;
}
```

**Pro:** does it all in one selector

**Con:** looks unstable and I feel like it's a bit ambiguous

### Idea 2

---

```
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed *{
    display:none;
}
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:hover *{
    display:initial;
}


SECTION FIGURE.collapsed H1,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed H2,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed H3,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed H4,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed H5,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed H6{
    display:block;
}
```

**Pro:** Classic CSS, easier to understand

**Cons:** Overrides previously set styles; doesn't seem like `display:initial;` is valid CSS, though it works.

Comment: `display: initial` is valid CSS; it just isn't very widely-supported yet (AFAIK only WebKit supports it). If you're trying to reset an element to what its default `display` value would be though, that's not what `initial` does; that keyword always resets it to `inline` regardless of what element it is because that's the *initial* value as defined by the spec.

Comment: Why can't you just have a class "collapsed" that makes things display: none? I'm afraid you are being overly specific for what your needs are.

`.collapsed { display: none; }`

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle because I want `collapsed` to work differently on different DOM elements

Comment: I'm removing my answer anyway - it's not needed and I already have a comment above about `initial` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a combination of what you have would be best. You can eliminate the `display: initial` by doing the `:not(:hover)` but reset all the heading elements (which normally would have been `display: block` anyway.

**Update**: needed to get the selector specificity up by adding `:not(:hover)` to all. [See fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/3HxXV/1/) (Note: the h2.1 tag is still hidden because it is *inside* a `div` [this is what BoltClock noted in his discussion]).

```
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) * {
    display:none;
} 

SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) H1,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) H2,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) H3,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) H4,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) H5,
SECTION FIGURE.collapsed:not(:hover) H6{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to encapsulate non-header content in some form of container. Perhaps a div or an HTML5 semantic container depending on your case. Apply a class to these content containers and then use one short, single query to hide this content. As hiding the container will automatically hide its contents, you have a short, simple and most importantly understandable solution with very little additional markup.

---

I should have initially mentioned that doing this does deviate from your original desire to strictly use CSS. Here you use JavaScript to handle the events, and CSS to manage the displaying and hiding of information. I find this cleaner than having the headers' CSS dictate the style of the content, but that's just me.

Anyways, a very simple implementation of this would be as follows. If you implement this you'll want to refactor to make it more robust (using the second child isn't very refactor-proof), but you get the idea.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Content</h1>
    <div style="display: none">
        This is some hidden content
    </div>
</div>

document.getElementById("wrapper").onmouseenter = function () {
    this.children[1].style.display = "block";
};

document.getElementById("wrapper").onmouseleave = function () {
    this.children[1].style.display = "none";
};
```